# How to write files in Docker Images?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-image

I've copied a file into a docker image with:

```
COPY dbconfig.xml /var/app/dbconfig.xml
```

After that I tried to replace some values in the file with:

```
RUN sed -i "s/PASSWD/$dbpasswd/" /var/app/dbconfig.xml
```

Note that $dbpassword is an ENV Variable.

When I check the contents of config.xml, by starting a container of that image and running a bash inside it, nothing has changed in the dbconfig.xml.

Now I think I misunderstand some fundamentals of docker images..

I even tested to create a simple file:

```
RUN echo "test" > newfile.txt
```

which seems to be deleted after the call..
I know that each **RUN** statement creates an **new layer** and after the statement it gets removed(?).

I'm confused. Why does something like installing software with

```
RUN apt-get install -y some-package
```

doesn't get removed and creating a simple file does get removed?

So.. how can I change files inside docker images at image-build-time?

**Dockerfile**:

```
FROM dchevell/jira-software:8.0

COPY dbconfig.xml /var/atlassian/application-data/jira/dbconfig.xml
WORKDIR /var/atlassian/application-data/jira

# set default password to admin
ENV dbpasswd=admin

RUN sed -i "s/PASSWD/$dbpasswd/" dbconfig.xml \
 && cat dbconfig.xml 

RUN echo "test" > newfile.txt
```

**dbconfig.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jira-database-config>
  <name>defaultDS</name>
  <delegator-name>default</delegator-name>
  <database-type>postgres72</database-type>
  <schema-name>public</schema-name>
  <jdbc-datasource>
    <url>jdbc:postgresql://docker-postgres:5432/jiradb</url>
    <driver-class>org.postgresql.Driver</driver-class>
    <username>atlasdb</username>
    <password>PASSWD</password>
    <pool-test-while-idle>true</pool-test-while-idle>
  </jdbc-datasource>
</jira-database-config>
```

**Update 1**

Confusingly, when I COPY something in the WORKDIR folder, it persists, but when I try to modify it afterwards with SED, these changes do not persist! I think there is some really dark magic happening in the background..
Maybe I try to bind mount my preconfigured dbconfig.xml within docker-compose and see if that helps..

**Update 2**

From the [Docker Documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#notes-about-specifying-volumes):

> Changing the volume from within the Dockerfile: If any build steps
>   change the data within the volume after it has been declared, those
>   changes will be discarded.

I totally missed that! Thanks David for pointing me there:) So creating and writing Files DOES work as expected, but be careful with VOLUME directories. RUN statements do not work here.
So to address this issue, the best practice would be to bind mount the file into that volume.

Comment: You are using `config.xml` and `dbconfig.xml` in different places

Comment: sry, I mispelled it in the question. I updated it. Still the file doesn't get updated..

Comment: can you add your Dockerfile here, and docker-compose file as well if you are using it.

Comment: added. I dont use compose in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at [the Dockerfile for that base image](https://bitbucket.org/dchevell/docker-atlassian-jira-software/src/b662f3a8399c6f196578a50caa3ca2bb0071ebe5/Dockerfile?at=base-8&fileviewer=file-view-default), it says in part

```
ENV JIRA_HOME /var/atlassian/application-data/jira
VOLUME ["${JIRA_HOME}"]
```

Once you execute a VOLUME statement in a Dockerfile, [later Dockerfile statements can't make any more changes in that specific directory](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#notes-about-specifying-volumes).

Given that the sorts of things you're trying to change are very installation-specific settings (admin password, database settings) I wouldn't try to build an image out of these.  Instead I'd use the `docker run -v` option to inject the configuration file at runtime.

Comment: Ahh! I totally missed that behaviour with VOLUME statement. Now everything makes sense! But weird enough is, that COPY seems to work regardlessly. Just the RUN statements doesnt have effect. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Each `RUN` statement does not create an intermediate container but creates a new layer on union file system, which is read only. When you run an image, a special writable layer is created for this container and all the changes you make on this container are written to this layer. (except the volumes. which is a different concept). That is why docker is able to share the same image (or even layers) between containers safely, without affecting each other. You can check [docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/overlayfs-driver/) for more information.

For your question, you should see every change you make on build time in the running instance of this image, unless you somehow delete or overwrite them.

Comment: short but well written

Comment: thanks for explanation. So you mean when I run the image I should see the newfile.txt file? Unfortunately that is not the case..

Answer (score 1):

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42400290/create-files-folders-on-docker-compose-build-or-docker-compose-up).

The commands you are running are correct and they *should* create the files. What I suspect is that when you run your container, the jira application is overwriting the `WORKDIR` you have specified.

Try this Dockerfile:

```
WORKDIR /var/atlassian/application-data/jira

# set default password to admin
ENV dbpasswd=admin

RUN sed -i "s/PASSWD/$dbpasswd/" dbconfig.xml \
 && cat dbconfig.xml 


WORKDIR /testtest
RUN touch test.txt
RUN echo "test" > newfile.txt

WORKDIR  /var/atlassian/application-data/jira
```

Now if you start the container, you can see that the files are being created inside the /testtest folder.

If you want your changes to the dbconfig.xml file to persist you should try using volumes to bind the local dbconfig.xml with the jira folder.

Thanks for this interesting question :)

Comment: this could be pointing in the right direction.. the temp files get indeed created but the dbconfig.xml in the workdir doesn't get updated. So maybe jira does something in the background that I dont know.. But than I don't understand why my dbconfig.xml gets copied in there and persists.. only SED seems to get reset after RUN..

Comment: Try copying a dummy dbconfig.xml with gibberish content. If the same file persists then there is some deeper issue, but if it gets overwrittern with a default version by jira, then its a jira issue.

Comment: copy seems to persist, but changing the files afterwards with sed, does not persist o.0